# npm generator-ionic Install Requires yo@>=1.0.0

Tags: npm, ionic-framework, yeoman

I'm trying to install generator-ionic, and I get the following fatal error:

`EPEERINVALID generator-ionic@0.7.3 requires a peer of yo@>=1.0.0 but none was installed`

I'm using node 0.12.17, npm 3.3.6, and yo 1.4.7, so I do not understand what isn't satisfied.

Comment: How are you trying to install it? Is yo installed globally?

Comment: how did you solved it?

Comment: I have different versions but basically the same problem....did you solved it?

Comment: Try running npm install -g yo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@chrysanhy I think I found the issue. I just downgraded my npm version to 2.7.4 and when I ran the command `npm install generator-ionic-g` the following message appeared:

> npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency yo@>=1.0.0 included from generator-ionic will no longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.

Now the ionic-generator is working fine on my machine. Hope this helps you and everyone who is facing the same problem.

Comment: How did you solve the warning that `Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.`?